# how to handle internet not avaialble while uploading the file to s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iot, boto3

I have written scheduler program in python to uploading file to AWS S3 at a particular time(using scheduler).

if internet connection is not available at that time , I'm getting **`socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`** exception.

This breaks the total flow, so that i need to restart the program.

How to handle this situation in a graceful way, so that when internet resumes my file get upload process starts.

Below is my scheduler job code:

```
def job():
    serialNo = getserial()
    print('schedule working.......')
    yesterday_date=date.today() - timedelta(1)

    # one day file path 
    file_path="/home/pi/Desktop/bme280_elf_new/reading/"+str(yesterday_date)+".csv" 

    # file move are upload file from cloud here
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    Bucketname = 'Bucketname' 

    conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1',
       aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
       aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
       is_secure=True,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
       calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
       )

    bucket = conn.get_bucket(Bucketname)

    print ('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' %
           (file_path, Bucketname))

    def percent_cb(complete, total):
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = str(serialNo)+'-'+str(yesterday_date)+'.csv'
    k.set_contents_from_filename(file_path,
    cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

Initiating scheduler by ,

```
schedule.every().day.at("00:10").do(job) # run at midnight 00:10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: updated my question and uploaded my code. review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its pretty simple , you can achieve it with the help of urllib2. here is the sample.**Note** urllib2 support only in python-2.x

**To check internet connection**

```
import urllib2

def is_connected():
        try:
            url = "http://www.google.com"
            urllib2.urlopen(url)
            return True
        except urllib2.URLError:
            pass
        return False
```

**File upload function**:

```
def fileUploadJob(BUCKET_NAME,AWS_REGION):
serialNo = getserial()
yesterday_date=date.today() - timedelta(1)

while True:
    if is_connected():
        conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(<Aws-region>,<Access_key>
              ,<secert-key>,
            is_secure=True,
            calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
            )
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

        FILE_PATH="/home/pi/Desktop/bme280_elf_new/reading/"+
                 str(yesterday_date)+".csv" 

        print ('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % 
        (FILE_PATH, BUCKET_NAME))

        def percent_cb(complete, total):
            sys.stdout.write('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()


        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = str(serialNo)+'-'+str(yesterday_date)+'.csv'
        k.set_contents_from_filename(FILE_PATH,
            cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
        time.sleep(10)

        break
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```